# $C[0,1]$ is not a Grothendieck space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ is called a Grothendieck space if $\text{weak}^{*}$-null sequences in $X^{*}$ are weakly null.  Some of the classical Grothendieck spaces are the $C(\Omega)$ spaces if $\Omega$ is extremally disconnected. However, $C[0,1]$ is not a Grothendieck space. This fact can easily be deduced from some well-known characterizations of Grothendieck spaces, such as, $C(\Omega)$ is a Grothendieck space if and only if it does not contain any complemented copy of $c_{0}$. But my concern is whether there is a direct proof of this fact, that is, a construction of a $\text{weak}^{*}$-null sequence $(\mu_{n})_{n}$ in $C[0,1]^{*}$ which is not weakly null.

Comment: Replacing $C[0,1]$ with $C[-1,1]$ for convenience, let $h_n$ be the "obvious" function in $L^1[-1,1]$ whichh as norm $1$ and mean zero and is supported on the interval $[-1/n, 1/n]$. If we view each $h_n$ as a measure on $[-1,1]$ then I think this should have the required properties - let me know if this doesn't work dor some reason

Comment: @YemonChoi  Thanks, Yemon. Could you describe the function $h_{n}$ clearer? I do not know what mean zero is.

Comment: @YemonChoi  I guess that mean zero means that $\int h_{n}=0$. I can prove that $\int f h_{n}\rightarrow 0$ for each $f\in C[-1.1]$. But I can not prove that the sequence $(h_{n})_{n}$ is weakly null as a sequence of measures on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @YemonChoi  Sorry. I can not prove that the sequence $(h_{n})_{n}$ is not weakly null as a sequence of measures on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Dongyang Chen: The point is that this sequence converges to $\delta_0$. It is not a  weakly null sequence. Try $\mu_n := n \cdot \lambda^1|_{[0,1/n]} - \delta_0$. I think it will do the job.

Comment: @DieterKadelka: I'm not sure I follow. The sequence $(h_n)$ in $C([-1,1])^*$ does indeed weak${}^*$-converge to $0$, but it is not weakly convergent to any point.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck: You are right. The last sentence in the question irritated me, since it is not quite correct. Not beig weakly null doen't suffice.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck: Is this not what we need, to find a weak-*-0-convergent sequence which is not weakly convergent at all?

Comment: @Dieter: If the sequence is weak$^*$ convergent to $0$ and weakly convergent to something, then something $=0$; so one just has to check weak convergence to $0$.

Comment: @DieterKadelka: Yes, indeed, we need a sequence that is weak${}^*$-convergent to $0$, but not weakly convergent; and the sequence $(h_n)$ suggested by Yemon Choi does the job. I was just wondering why you mentioned $\delta_0$ in your first comment, since the sequence $(h_n)$ has nothing to do with $\delta_0$.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck: I was confused by the notation. I considered $h_n$ as a measure and then compared it with $\delta_0$ In principle it is a variant of the answer of Dirk Werner, I only had $n \cdot \lambda^1|{[0,1/n]}-\delta_0$ instead of $\delta_{1/n}-\delta_0$. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @DieterKadelka: Thank you for your response. I see.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider $\delta_{1/n}-\delta_0$; this defines a weak$^*$ null sequences which is not weakly null; e.g., $\langle \delta_{1/n}-\delta_0, \chi_{\{0\}} \rangle \not\to 0$. So if $\Omega$ contains a nontrivial convergent sequence, $C(\Omega)$ cannot  be a Grothendieck space.

Comment: Nice - I like this argument better than my original suggestion, since it seems to pinpoint the key "largeness" property required for a given $\Omega$ to yield the Grothendieck space property for $C(\Omega)$

Comment: More generally, if $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space for which $C(K)$ is a Grothendieck space, then every convergent sequence in $K$ is eventually constant.

Comment: @Bill: I think I said so in my answer...

Comment: I see. Sorry, Dirk.

Comment: Bill, no problem!

Answer (score 4):

Let us define $h_{n}(t)=\frac{n}{2}$, $t\in [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and $h_{n}(t)=-\frac{n}{2}$, $t\in [-\frac{1}{n},0]$ and $h_{n}(t)=0$ otherwise. Then $\int f\cdot h_{n}\rightarrow 0$ for each $f\in C[-1,1]$. This means that $(h_{n})_{n}$ is $\text{weak}^{*}$-null.

Define $g(t)=-1$, $t\in [-1,0]$ and $g(t)=1$, $t\in [0,1]$. Then $\int g\cdot h_{n}=1$ for all $n$. This implies that $(h_{n})_{n}$ is not weakly null.